# ¿Es una ofensa decir la palabra "caray"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, vulgaridades

¿Qué significa la palabra "caray", es una ofensa decirle a alguien "caray"?

> ¡Caray! Que estas haciendo aqui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Caray* is already an euphemism (for *carajo*, which out of it's interjection function, means *penis*). Therefore, it doesn't sound bad. But that's precisely why sometimes it's not used and other interjections, like the already mentioned in other answers, are prefered over *caray*.

Answer (score 6):

La palabra *caray* es un eufemismo derivado de *carajo*. En español tenemos unos cuantos, como *ondia* (por *hostia*), *jobar* o *jopé* (derivados de *joder*)...

En todos estos casos, el eufemismo se considera aceptable en casi cualquier situación, mientras que las exclamaciones originales se consideran malsonantes. Por supuesto, las malsonantes se usan mucho, pero hay ambientes o situaciones en las que resultan inapropiadas. En cambio, incluso un niño puede decir *caray* y a nadie le va a sonar mal.

Comment: En la zona oriental de cuba se usa mucho caray...en la forma en que tu lo explicas

Comment: Lo siento. No había visto que tú ya habías escrito que era un eufemismo. Ahora borro mi respuesta. 1 min después... No puedo hacerlo ahora, pues está como aceptada. Después lo hago.

Comment: @c.p. Si te la han aceptado, déjala. Al parecer, al autor de la pregunta le ha gustado más cómo lo explicas tú.

Answer (score 3):

Caray es una interjección de sorpresa. En España prácticamente no se utiliza, se considera anticuada y muy poco "potente", coloquialmente se hace mucho más uso de "joder" como interjección de sorpresa, si bien esta última puede ser ofensiva o poco adecuada en según qué contextos mientras que Caray no será ofensivo prácticamente para nadie.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia no es una ofensa.  Es una interjección.  Sin embargo poco se usa ya,  personalmente la usa mi padre.  Por otra parte en Colombia su uso fue muy prominente en Bogotá,  la capital de Colombia.  Fuera de Bogota no se usa o usaba.  De hecho el uso de esta palabra permite inferir que quien la usa es de Bogota o ha vivido en Bogota mucho tiempo.

```
Caray que sorpresa,  no esperaba esto!  Que agradable!
```

Esta frase como ejemplo de una situacion en que una persona recibe una invitación no esperada a almorzar,  por que ese dia cumple años.

Answer (score 0):

Caray es como todos dicen, una interjección para la palabra carajo. Sin embargo, Carajo no significa pene como dicen en los comentarios. En los poemas españoles de los 1500, carajo era una palabra para referirse a la vulva o mas precisamente, a la vagina. 
De otro lado, es poco usada, sin embargo, depende del estrato social de quien habla. Personas de alta estrata social aun la utilizan. 
No se considera un improperio ya que, aunque derive de una connotación sexual, es usada en otro contexto, usualmente de sorpresa y en la mayoría de las ocasiones, de alegría. 
Cabe señalar que el carajo es la parte mas alta del mastil de un barco, donde se subía un marinero a velar si había tierra o enemigos cerca. Por eso la frase "Vete al carajo" lleva una connotación negativa. El irse a ese lugar significaba irse solo a un lugar lejos. Aunque tenias personas cerca (En el barco) estabas separado de ellas.